# ¿Cómo filtrar una lista tipo objeto con linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una lista `var lst = new List<ListViewModel>();`    que contiene  una cantidad de registros
Ahora yo hago esto :

```
return lst.GroupBy( x=> x.IdSolicitud).ToList();
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error : ***No se puede convertir el System.Linq.IGrouping  en Generic List***

¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

consulta:

```
public List<ListViewModel> LstViewModel(){

var lst = (from s in db.A_CC_Solicitud
                           join d in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle on s.IdSolicitud equals d.IdSolicitud
                           join dp in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle_Proveedor on d.IdSolicitudDetalle equals dp.IdSolicitudDetalle
                           join e in db.A_Empresa on s.IdEmpresa equals e.IdEmpresa
                           join t in db.A_CC_EstadoSolicitud on s.IdEstado equals t.IdEstado
                           join c in db.A_Contrato on s.IdContrato equals c.IdContrato into cs
                           from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { s, d, dp, e, c, t })
                           .AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(x => new ListViewModel
                           {
                               IdSolicitud = x.s.IdSolicitud,
                               IdEmpresa = x.s.IdEmpresa,
                               Empresa = x.e.Empresa,
                               FechaCrea = x.s.FechaCrea.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                               FechaVigencia = x.s.FechaVigencia.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                               FechaVigenciaProveedor = x.s.FechaVigenciaProveedor.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                               IdContrato = x.s.IdContrato,
                               Contrato = x.c != null ? x.c.Nombre : "",
                               IdEstado = x.s.IdEstado,
                               Estado = x.t.Estado2,
                               Titulo = x.s.Titulo,
                               IdDelegacion = x.s.IdDelegacion,
                               Marca = x.s.Marca,
                               UserName = usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == x.s.UserIdCrea.ToString()) != null ? usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == x.s.UserIdCrea.ToString()).Nombre : "",
                               Gestor = x.e.IdVendedor != null && x.e.IdVendedor != "" ? gestores.FirstOrDefault(m => m.IdGestor.ToLower() == x.e.IdVendedor.ToLower()).Nombre : gestores.First().Nombre,
                               NavigateUrl = x.t.IdEstado <= 30 ? "/CentralCompras/Solicitud/Edit?id=" + x.s.IdSolicitud :
                                            x.t.IdEstado == 35 || x.t.IdEstado == 40 ? "/CentralCompras/RecepcionOferta/Edit?id=" + x.s.IdSolicitud :
                                            x.t.IdEstado >= 50 ? "/CentralCompras/OfertaEnviadaCliente/Edit?id=" + x.s.IdSolicitud
                                            : "/CentralCompras/Solicitud/Edit?id=" + x.s.IdSolicitud,
                               FechaModifica = x.s.FechaModifica ?? x.s.FechaCrea,
                         

                           }).OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaModifica).ToList();
                           
                           return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var listaAgrupada = (from l in lst 
                     group l by l.IdSolicitud into grupo 
                     select new
                     {
                         IdSolicitud = grupo.Key,
                         objetos = grupo
                     }).ToList();
```

Esta consulta devuelve un **objeto anónimo**, el cual va a realizar la agrupación por la **propiedad idSolicitud**; **grupo.Key** sería cada número de solicitud por el que se realiza la agrupación y **grupo** sería todos los objetos que tienen en común el mismo **idSolicitud**.

Para imprimir habría que hacer **dos ciclos foreach anidados**, uno que recorra cada key y otro que recorra por cada key todos los objetos agrupados por esta llave:

```
foreach(var g in listaAgrupada)
{
   //Imprime g.idSolicitud
   foreach(var o in g.objetos)
   {
      //Imprime cada objeto del grupo
   }
}
```